# independency given an event and its influence in total probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayesian

Suppose that X is independent of Y, and let Z be any event. Is it true that:

$$
\mathbb{P}[X,Y|Z]=\mathbb{P}[X|Z]*\mathbb{P}[Y|Z]
$$

Moreover, if that is true, then:

\begin{align*}
(\mathbb{P}[X|Z]\mathbb{P}[Z]+\mathbb{P}[X|Z^c]\mathbb{P}[Z^c])*(\mathbb{P}[Y|Z]\mathbb{P}[Z]+\mathbb{P}[Y|Z^c]\mathbb{P}[Z^c])&=\mathbb{P}[X]\mathbb{P}[Y]\\
&=\mathbb{P}[X,Y]\\
&=\mathbb{P}[X,Y|Z]\mathbb{P}[Z]+\mathbb{P}[X,Y|Z^c]\mathbb{P}[Z^c]
\end{align*}

and so on... but, I have a counterexample for the last equation. So I'm getting confused, what's wrong here?

Comment: First equation is false. Take $Z=X\cup Y$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- the unconditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ does not imply conditional independence given any event. You can choose some event that gives you information about both $X$ and $Y$ simultaneously. For example, let $X,Y,Z$ be i.i.d. and consider the event $A = \left\{X \leq Z, Y \leq Z\right\}$.